# Third-party payment method for Android app outside of Google Pay and possible issues

Tags: google-play

I have an app on Google Play that uses Google Play's billing system for payments.
I'm exploring the possibility of releasing an alternate version of this app, with **identical package name and signed with the same key**, but implementing a third-party payment method (such as cryptocurrency).
The intention is to distribute this modified version **exclusively outside of the Google Play platform**. Is this feasible?

I have looked into this matter and have come to the conclusion that it falls into a kind of 'gray area' within Google's rules. I would appreciate any information on this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just considering the exact same. **My understanding is that this whould not be against Google's terms.**

In the [description of Play App Signing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756?hl=en), it is stated explicitly that the signed APKs may also be distributed outside of Google Play, and the [Play App Signing Terms of Service](https://play.google/play-app-signing-terms/) do not restrict the use of the signed APKs.

The [Goolge Play payments policy](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9858738) only applies to "Play-distributed apps", and I do not see how the version of your app that you would distribute exclusively outside of Google Play would become a "Play-distributed app" just because another version with the same package name and signing key is distributed through Google Play.

If you use Play App Signing for the two different versions, you will anyway need to use different version codes (the Play console does not allow to upload two bundles with the same version code), so that the versions would clearly have a "different identity".

And if you upload the version for distribution outside of Google Play only on the *App bundle explorer* for signing, I don't see why Google should check it for compliance with the terms for Play-distributed apps.

An advantage of using the same signing key for the version for distribution outside of Google Play is that it can then query for purchases made in the Play-distributed version.

I would also be interested in further opinions / experiences.